# Clion stopped to see "boost/algorithm/string.hpp"

Tags: c++, boost, clion

Yesterday everything compiled. Today:

```
fatal error: boost/algorithm/string.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include "boost/algorithm/string.hpp"
```

This happens for the second time. Last time I removed Clion cache foldier `.CLion2018.1` and needed to put actiovation code again, ..., but then everything worked again.
How can I resolve this?

I used git before that happened and pull some changes. But everything compiles in terminal, not in clion only because it ceased to see that boost file.

Comment: Not enough information. Do you use some version control system? If you do does it work with older code version? Did you tried to clean project? Did you do some modifications in project?

Comment: I used git. Everything compiles in terminal, but clion doesn't see that file. How can I clean the project?

Comment: what operating system? Looks like some invalid system configuration, for example some environment variable is set for terminal, but it is not set system wide so clion do not see it.

Comment: ubuntu 18. What or who could set an env variable?